# Swift optional type error for camera setup

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am trying to add camera functionality to my IOS app.  I receive the error 
"Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AVCaptureDevice]'"

What should I fix?

```
func prepareCamera() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices {
        captureDevice = availableDevices.first
        beginSession()
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to check with `if let`, since the result is not an optional. Replace it with a `let` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

```
func prepareCamera() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices.first {
        captureDevice = device
        beginSession()
    }

}
```